# Bootable USB with windows in it fails to load on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub2, dual-boot

My Current Problem:-

*I have ubuntu 18 as my OS and when I try to boot from a USB containing windows 7 bootable hoping to dual boot my system, it fails to boot from USB and loads my Ubuntu after certain weird messages.

*Ubuntu then flashes several times before loading when it failed to boot from  Windows USB.

To start off, I had windows 10 installed on my system. I needed to format it and perform a fresh dual boot with windows 7 and mint 17. Here is what I did, please find the erroneous step:-

1. I made a mint 17 USB bootable disk and started my system using it.
2. I made a partition table allocating desired disk spaces for my mint and windows partitions and formatted my system.
3. Mint installation failed because of Grub loader error.
4. After several retries I tried a bootable with Ubuntu and it was successfully installed.
5. Now I want to install windows 7 in it, but it somehow not loading files from the bootable USB and is weirdly directing me to Ubuntu screen after several flashes and weird error messages on the terminal. Why is it happening ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Unix group.

Comment: Regardless of which SE group this is best suited for, I'd wager the "certain weird messages" are kind of important. More detail would also be needed.

Answer (score 0):

- From Ubuntu: Follow instructions on this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to install and run Boot-Repair. This will fix most common installation problems with Grub2. This will probably fix the usb problem.
- Make sure that on your boot MENU, booting from flash drive(external disk/usb) is enabled and has priority. you will easily find how to do that if you google $your_machines_name + "boot from usb".

Install Windows (without partitioning the disk), and then install Ubuntu as dual boot(in the installation set-up you can define how much volume to give to each OS). This way Grub2 will be your bootloader and not windows' MBR

I should mention that dual boot is always a troublesome road. The lesser of two evils, is to install Windows then Ubuntu, because Grub2 is more friendly with multiple OSs running on same platform.